# How to position div to be flush against another div?

Tags: html, layout, css

I have a main div in the center of my page with an id of "panel".

I want to position another div, "toolbar" so that it is top aligned and flush against the side of the "panel" div.

Like so [image: Layout]

And I want the panel div to remain centered. (Currently doing this by setting margin-left/margin-right to auto)

Absolute positioning on the toolbar breaks when I resize the window.

I've also tried floating them inside a wrapper, but invariably this moves the panel from the center...

This feels like it should simple, am I overlooking something? What is the best way to accomplish this?

Current live example here:
[Example](http://tcusers.com/examples/9145982752/)

Thanks for any advice..

Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="toolbar">
            Toolbar
        </div>
        <div id="panel">
            Panel
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#toolbar{
    border:1px solid black;
    color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
}

#panel{
    border:1px solid black;
    color: blue;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ywc5f/

In the HTML, you can move `#toolbar` inside `#panel`, *then* use absolute positioning.

**CSS:**

```
#panel {
    position: relative;
}
#toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    left: -102px; /* width of #toolbar + border */
    top: -1px; /* border */
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="panel">
    Panel

    <div id="toolbar">
        Toolbar
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I like that solution. Markup makes more sense to my mind - the toolbar "belongs to" the panel.

Answer (score 0):

User floats. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/SRAYg/).

Comment: The second float in that example is not centered.

Answer (score 0):

you're using an absolute width for both of those so put them in another div as a wrapper and give it the width of the the middle one + (the narrow one x 2)

then use auto on the new wrapper div and use float left on both the interior divs